# Neural Network: Mysterious ReLu

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I've been building a programming language detector, i.e., a classifier of code snippets, as part of a bigger project.
My baseline model is pretty straight-forward: tokenize the input and encode the snippets as *bag-of-words* or,
in this case, *bag-of-tokens*, and make a simple NN on top of these features.

[image: boxes]

The input to NN is a fixed-length array of counters of most distinctive tokens, such as `"def"`,
`"self"`, `"function"`, `"->"`, `"const"`, `"#include"`, etc., that are automatically extracted from the corpus.
The idea is that these tokens are pretty unique to programming languages, so even this naive approach should get
high accuracy score.

```
Input:
  def   1
  for   2
  in    2
  True  1
  ):    3
  ,:    1

  ...

Output: python
```

### Setup

I got 99% accuracy pretty quickly and decided that's the sign that it works just as expected. Here's the model
(a full runnable script is [here](https://github.com/maxim5/code-inspector/blob/9ef86db033e926f7b80c98cee4d1a45a68c208aa/model/dnn_model.py)):

```python
# Placeholders
x = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, vocab_size], dtype=tf.float32, name='x')
y = tf.placeholder(shape=[None], dtype=tf.int32, name='y')
training = tf.placeholder_with_default(False, shape=[], name='training')

# One hidden layer with dropout
reg = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(0.01)
hidden1 = tf.layers.dense(x, units=96, kernel_regularizer=reg, 
                          activation=tf.nn.elu, name='hidden1')
dropout1 = tf.layers.dropout(hidden1, rate=0.2, training=training, name='dropout1')

# Output layer
logits = tf.layers.dense(dropout1, units=classes, kernel_regularizer=reg,
                         activation=tf.nn.relu, name='logits')

# Cross-entropy loss
loss = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, abels=y))

# Misc reports: accuracy, correct/misclassified samples, etc.
correct_predicted = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, y, 1, name='in-top-k')
prediction = tf.argmax(logits, axis=1)
wrong_predicted = tf.logical_not(correct_predicted, name='not-in-top-k')
x_misclassified = tf.boolean_mask(x, wrong_predicted, name='misclassified')
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_predicted, tf.float32), name='accuracy')
```

The output is pretty encouraging:

```python
iteration=5  loss=2.580  train-acc=0.34277
iteration=10  loss=2.029  train-acc=0.69434
iteration=15  loss=2.054  train-acc=0.92383
iteration=20  loss=1.934  train-acc=0.98926
iteration=25  loss=1.942  train-acc=0.99609
Files.VAL mean accuracy = 0.99121             <-- After just 1 epoch!

iteration=30  loss=1.943  train-acc=0.99414
iteration=35  loss=1.947  train-acc=0.99512
iteration=40  loss=1.946  train-acc=0.99707
iteration=45  loss=1.946  train-acc=0.99609
iteration=50  loss=1.944  train-acc=0.99902
iteration=55  loss=1.946  train-acc=0.99902
Files.VAL mean accuracy = 0.99414
```

Test accuracy was also around 1.0. Everything looked perfect.

### Mysterious ReLu

But then I noticed that I put `activation=tf.nn.relu` into the final dense layer (`logits`), which is clearly **a bug**:
there is no need to discard negative scores before `softmax`, because they indicate the classes with low probability.
Zero threshold will only make these classes artificially more probable, which would be a mistake. Getting rid of it should only make the model more robust and confident in the correct class.

That's what I thought.
So I replaced it with `activation=None`, run the model again and then a surprising thing happened:
the performance didn't improve. At all. In fact, it **degraded significantly**:

```python
iteration=5  loss=5.236  train-acc=0.16602
iteration=10  loss=4.068  train-acc=0.18750
iteration=15  loss=3.110  train-acc=0.37402
iteration=20  loss=5.149  train-acc=0.14844
iteration=25  loss=2.880  train-acc=0.18262
Files.VAL mean accuracy = 0.28711

iteration=30  loss=3.136  train-acc=0.25781
iteration=35  loss=2.916  train-acc=0.22852
iteration=40  loss=2.156  train-acc=0.39062
iteration=45  loss=1.777  train-acc=0.45312
iteration=50  loss=2.726  train-acc=0.33105
Files.VAL mean accuracy = 0.29362
```

The accuracy got better with training, but never surpassed 91-92%. I changed the activation back and forth several times,
varying different parameters (layer size, dropout, regularizer, extra layers, anything) and always had the same outcome:
**the "wrong" model hit 99% immediately, while the "right" model barely achieved 90% after 50 epochs**. According to
tensorboard, there was no big difference in weight distribution: the gradients didn't die out and both models learned
normally.

How is this possible? How can the final ReLu make a model so much superior? Especially if this ReLu is a bug?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Prediction distribution

After playing around with it for a while, I decided to visualize the actual prediction distribution for both models:

```
predicted_distribution = tf.nn.softmax(logits, name='distribution')
```

Below are the histograms of the distributions and how they evolved over time.

**With ReLu (wrong model)**

[image: predicted-distribution]

**Without ReLu (correct model)**

[image: predicted-distribution]

The first histogram makes sense, most of probabilities are close to `0`.
But the histogram of the ReLu model is **suspicious**: the values seem to concentrate around `0.15` after few iterations. Printing the actual predictions confirmed this idea:

```
[0.14286 0.14286 0.14286 0.14286 0.14286 0.14286 0.14286]
[0.14286 0.14286 0.14286 0.14286 0.14286 0.14286 0.14286]
```

I had 7 classes (for 7 different languages at that moment) and `0.14286` is `1/7`. It turns out, the "perfect" model learned to output
`0` logits, which in turn translated in uniform prediction.

But how can *this* distribution be reported as 99% accurate?

### `tf.nn.in_top_k`

Before diving into [`tf.nn.in_top_k`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/in_top_k) I checked an alternative way to compute accuracy:

```
true_correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, 1), tf.cast(y, tf.int64))
alternative_accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(true_correct, tf.float32))
```

... which performs honest comparison of the highest predicted class and the ground truth. The result is this:

```
iteration=2  loss=3.992  train-acc=0.13086  train-alt-acc=0.13086
iteration=4  loss=3.590  train-acc=0.13086  train-alt-acc=0.12207
iteration=6  loss=2.871  train-acc=0.21777  train-alt-acc=0.13672
iteration=8  loss=2.466  train-acc=0.37695  train-alt-acc=0.16211
iteration=10  loss=2.099  train-acc=0.62305  train-alt-acc=0.10742
iteration=12  loss=2.066  train-acc=0.79980  train-alt-acc=0.17090
iteration=14  loss=2.016  train-acc=0.84277  train-alt-acc=0.17285
iteration=16  loss=1.954  train-acc=0.91309  train-alt-acc=0.13574
iteration=18  loss=1.956  train-acc=0.95508  train-alt-acc=0.06445
iteration=20  loss=1.923  train-acc=0.97754  train-alt-acc=0.11328
```

Indeed, `tf.nn.in_top_k` with `k=1` diverged from the right accuracy quickly and began to report fantasized 99% values.
So what does it do actually? Here's what [the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/in_top_k)
says about it:

> Says whether the targets are in the top K predictions.
>
> This outputs a `batch_size` bool array, an entry `out[i]` is true if the prediction for the target class is among the top k
>   predictions among all predictions for example i.
>   Note that the behavior of `InTopK` differs from the `TopK` op in its handling of ties;
>   if multiple classes have the same prediction value and straddle the top-k boundary,
>   **all of those classes are considered to be in the top k**.

*That's* what it is. If the probabilities are uniform (which actually means "I have no idea"), they are all correct. The situation is even worse, because if the logits distribution is *almost* uniform, softmax may transform it into *exactly* uniform distribution, as can be seen in this simple example:

```
x = tf.constant([0, 1e-8, 1e-8, 1e-9])
tf.nn.softmax(x).eval()
# >>> array([0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25], dtype=float32)
```

... which means that every nearly uniform prediction, may be considered "correct" according to `tf.nn.in_top_k` spec.

### Conclusion

`tf.nn.in_top_k` is a dangerous choice of accuracy measure in tensorflow, because it may silently swallow wrong predictions
and report them as "correct". Instead, you should always use this long but trusted expression:

```
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, 1), tf.cast(y, tf.int64)), tf.float32))
```